# Which way is up and down?

Tags: git

In Git, you can merge upstream and downstream.

If you have main branch `a` and make a branch off that called `b`:
 I think it means merging `b` back to `a` or either merging `a` into `b`.

But which is which? And what's a good way to remember it?

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the eye of the beholder. All branches are created equal, and are endowed by their developer with certain inalienable rights. Amongst them rebase, diff, and pushing to origin.

If you branch off branch `a`, and create branch `b`, then later you can merge one to the other. There is no difference.